# Detecting mouse courser when is close to polyline

Tags: javascript

I have a programming question with some math weight. I have a map with shapes(polylines) drown on it. I can take the screen coordinates of that shapes and translate them to map coordinates and reverse. I am capturing mouse position and moving around the map. How can I recognize if I come in proximity to another shape drown on the map while I am moving the mouse. I was thinking to create a radius of points around the mouse cursor, then constantly looping trough available shapes (I imagine I can load their coordinates in arrays) for a match. However that will be very slow I think. The point is that when I am in proximity (for example 15px) I will snap the muse position to that close shape. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now - if you really want to make it perfect - you can calculate the distance of a cursor to each line segment.

For each line segment (defined by points D and E)

Calculate line formula for segment DE in format:

Ax + By + C = 0

A = D.y - E.y

B = E.x - D.x

C = (plug in point D) = -1 * (A * D.x + B * D.y)

Now plug in your cursor position to the formula:

A * cursor.x + B * cursor.y + C = YOUR DISTANCE TO THE LINE SEGMENT

*One thing - this is distance to the unbounded line.  You now want to make sure that you are between the two segment points.  So make sure the angles in your cursor, D, E triangle are all < 90 degrees.  A number of ways to do that, look into the dot product formula to learn a fast one.

Now if anlges are less than 90, use the distance to the line, else, use the min distance to either point of segment (D & E).  Now you have a complete snap to lines functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you have every point / line segment of the shapes (which you should with the polylines), here is a possible quick and simple routine:

For each shape
 Figure center of shape by averaging each constituent point (i.e. - for a pentagon, add all five point.x up, divide by 5 - do same for all point.y).  Call this average shape.x and shape.y.  Use distance formula to figure proximity to your mouse.  (Mouse.x - Shape.x)^2 + (Mouse.y - Shape.y)^2... you don't have to take the square root of that since you are only interested in the closest shape.

Keep track of the minimum distance "squared" for each shape.  The minimum is your closest shape center.

If you want snap to behavior with a maximum range, just also make sure the distance squared is < pixel distance squared.

If you want to make it very effiecient, the shape centers do not need to be constantly refigured, just calculated once.  The center will scale and translate the same as any other point if you are converting between screen space and other coordinates as you mentioned.